# Removing rows that does not meet a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Date            Name    Score
Jan-1-2020  Jake    50
Jan-2-2020  Jake    30
Feb-1-2020  Paul    30
Jan-3-2020  Jake    30
Jan-2-2020  Paul    25
```

For each individual, I want to determine if they score less than 35% in a 2 or more days consecutive period

First, I arranged the table based on name and Date

```
Data = Data.sort_values(["Name","Date"], ascending = [True, True])
```

| Date | Name | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-1-2020 | Jake | 50. |
| Jan-2-2020 | Jake | 30 |
| Jan-3-2020 | Jake | 30 |
| Jan-2-2020 | Paul | 25 |
| Feb-1-2020 | Paul | 30 |

I want to obtain one row for each individual that shows their minimum score over a period of 2 or more consecutive days:

| Date | Name | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-3-2020 | Jake | 30 |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What if they score 32 and then 34?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`rolling.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.max.html) to count the number of values <= 35 per 2D:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

idx = (df
   .sort_values(by='Date')
   .assign(flag=lambda d: d['Score'].le(35))
   .groupby('Name', group_keys=False)
   .apply(lambda g: g.rolling('2D', on='Date')['flag'].sum())
)

print(df.loc[idx[idx>=2]])
```

Output:

```
        Date  Name  Score
2 2020-02-01  Paul     30
```